# how to understand this regex pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, less

Javascript regex pattern I find in less:

`/^([#.](?:[\w-]|\\(?:[A-Fa-f0-9]{1,6} ?|[^A-Fa-f0-9]))+)\s*\(/`

especially this section:

**\\(?:[A-Fa-f0-9]{1,6} ?|[^A-Fa-f0-9])**

Comment: [http://www.regexper.com/](http://www.regexper.com)

Comment: @epascarello: Having not come across http://www.regexper.com/ before, I love it. Thanks for posting!

Comment: Looks like a HEX color regex.

Comment: @elclanrs The `[^A-Fa-f0-9]` part makes it do more than that, most of which looks like escape sequences, but I haven't figured out the actual purpose of the regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
([#.](?:[\w-]|\\(?:[A-Fa-f0-9]{1,6} ?|[^A-Fa-f0-9]))+)\s*\(
```

[image]

Comment: have you drawn that yourself? Please provide a source.

Answer (score 1):

Let's work it from the inside out, using [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) as reference when necessary:

**(?:[A-Fa-f0-9]{1,6} ?|[^A-Fa-f0-9])**

`(?:)` is a non-capturing parenthesis.  It groups and matches, but doesn't save the results.  Inside that group is 1-6 hex digits followed by an optional space or any character other than a hex character.

**(?:[\w-]|\\ `above`)+**

Again, a non-capturing parenthesis, this time of `\w`, which is any alphanumeric character + _, and since there's `[\w-]`, that's "any alphanum + -_".  Then there's an or, a `\` character, and the above.  Together, that makes this parenthesis group read as: "Any single alphanumeric character, underscore or hyphen, or a backslash followed by either anything not a hexdigit or a hexstring of 1 to 6 characters."  The `+` means "at least 1 instance of the group."

**^([#.]`above`)\s*(**

Now we have `^[#.]` which means "the line must start with # or . followed by the above, with any number of spaces, followed by a left parenthesis.

**TL;DR:**

When you add that all up, you get:

"A line that starts with either `#` or `.` followed by one or more of:

- alphanumeric characters, _ or - OR
- a backslash followed by a one to six digit hexstring followed by a single optional space OR
- a backslash followed by a single nonhexdigit character

followed by any number of whitespace and then a `(`".

If a match is found, the entire part before the whitespace and `(` is stored in the result of the search.